# in node-webkit application the alert messages cutting off

Tags: javascript, alert, node-webkit

I am using node-webkit for hybrid application.In that the alert messages are cutting off.cant able to see the OK buttons..this happening for confirm and prompt also.So anyone please help me to short out this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What's your nw version and os? Maybe it's a bug similar to [this](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/433) or [this](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1050)

Comment: Am using windows xp and i have tried new versions (node-webkit-v0.6.3-win-ia32 , node-webkit-v0.7.1-win-ia32) of node-webkit and old versions also.

Comment: The link which u post also showing we have problem..Is there any solution ?

Comment: I changed the theme "windows classic" in windows Xp...now its working fine.

Comment: But the alert close is not working.If i click 'ok' button its disappearing but the close button doesn't do anything

Comment: Can `space` close the alert?It seems a bug similar to the links which I posted. Hopefully, it will be solved soon.

Comment: I have the same bug in 0.92 and 0.10RC1 :/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be dependent on the chosen windows theme.

When using Windows 7 Basic Theme message boxes are cut. When using Aero Theme everything looks right.

Workaround as of today: Implement your own alert boxes using javascript and css or tell users to use Windows Classic for XP and Aero for Win7.